# How to do logistic regression when one of the factors has unequal number of levels across the other factor?

Tags: logistic, experiment-design, categorical-encoding, nested-data

I am analyzing an experiment that has the following design:

```
    Factor1  Factor2 
     Level1  Level1
             Level2
     Level2  Level1.1
             Level1.2
             Level2
```

In other words, Factor2 has different number of levels across Factor1. I'd like to use logistic regression, but how should I set it up?  Is it legitimate to run two regressions ignoring one of the levels in each (e.g. Level1.1 or Level1.2)?

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258