# weighted one-hot encoding

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, nested-data

I am using one-hot encoding to transform my categorical variable. But it's not just a presence-absence situation. Consider the variable as a device that can have with different brands as well as different model numbers. So, for example it can be `Sony 10`, `Sony 10.5`, or `LG 2000`, `LG 3200`. The brands differ and the model numbers have their own range too.

What I did was something like this:

I convert:

```
---------------------------
|   Index   | Device      
---------------------------
|   0       | Sony,10 
|   1       | Sony,10.5
|   2       | LG,2000
|   3       | LG,3200
```

to:

```
---------------------------
|   Index   | Dev_Sony | Dev_LG      
---------------------------
|   0       | 10       | 0
|   1       | 10.5     | 0
|   2       | 0        | 2000
|   3       | 0        | 3200
```

**Question**: I am using multiple **linear regression**. Using the above encoding, the model numbers (e.g. 10 vs 10.5) are useful when comparing devices of the same brand, but I'm not sure if they make sense in comparison with other brands. So, I was wondering if there is a better way of encoding such data.

**UPDATE**

### based on the answer, my dataframe would look like this:

```
|   Index   | Dev_Sony | Dev_LG  | Model_Number   
---------------------------
|   0       | 1        | 0       | 10
|   1       | 1        | 0       | 10.5
|   2       | 0        | 1       | 2000
|   3       | 0        | 1       | 3200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two categorical variables, `Device` with values Sony, LG, ... and `Model_Number` with values 10, 10.5, 2000, 3200, ... . Then `Model_Number` is *nested* within `Device`.  See then [How do you deal with "nested" variables in a regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model)   for how to model this.

But, very shortly, if you are using R then use the *nesting operator* / in the formula language, `y ~  Device/Model_Number + ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using `Python`, if I understand your other post correctly, it should be modelled as "conditional variables": `y ~ Device + Device:Model_Number`? and why `Device/Model_num` rather than `Device*Model_num`? Can you give me a textbook reference where I can read more about this?

Comment: Those two notations are equivalent!

Comment: No, I mean `Dev/Num`  (which can be read Dev, and within Dev, Num) expands into `Dev + Dev:Num`. A good discussion is in https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387954578

Comment: I was implementing this today and realised that I forgot about one part. In practice, I'd still need to get the dummy variables for the devices. So, I'd still end-up with columns of unique devices. R should be doing the same behind the scene (I get the dummy_codes in Python using the Pandas library). Please have a look at the `Update` based on your answer. And then, I'll have `Dev` and `Dev*Num` in the formula.

Comment: The data frame in your update looks fine.

Comment: Also, multicollinearity itself is a problem anyway, since, in your approach, all dummy variables will be almost perfectly collinear with their interaction terms (interaction is 0 when a dummy variable is 0, and a positive number (`Dev*Num` when the dummy variable is 1) . My point is since they are collinear, we can then drop one of them, say the dummy variable itself, and we end up using only the interaction term, which is exactly what I used in the first place (the second dataframe in the question)