# Questions not applicable given a certain answer. How to analyze?

Tags: regression

So I am dealing with a questionnaire where given an answer on a specific questions the next three following questions are not applicable to the person.
I would like to include those variables in a regression as independent variables but I dont know how.
For example:

1. Do you own a car?
2. What is the color of the car?
3. What is the brand of the car?
4. How old is the car?

So there will be a high correlation between question 1 and the questions 2,3,4.
I could remove question 1 but multi collinearity between 2,3,4 remains because all people who do not own a car have a "not-applicable". Also I would lose the easily interpret-able effect of owning a car.

I also cant really impute those values as they are not missing at random.

Is there a way of solving it, or what would be search terms I could use to find an answer?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "dealing"?  That is, exactly how do you intend to use this set of related results?  What is the purpose of your analysis?

Comment: Oh sorry. I want to use those variable in a regression. I edited it

Comment: How, exactly?  As a response or as explanatory variables?

Comment: As predictors variables

Comment: This might be helpful:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258