# Dealing with NAs in Regression

Tags: regression, missing-data

Let's say I want to estimate the effects of wars in GDP. My data looks something like this, where war 1 was the first war in the country in that time period (but is not the same war), and LongWar1 is a variable which takes value 1 if the war lasted for longer than 3 months and 0 otherwise:

| Country | Year | Years since War 1 | Years since War 2 | Long War 1 | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1970 | 50 | 25 | 0 | 3,000,000 |
| Iraq | 1970 | -5 | 2 | 1 | 4,000,000 |

Of course wars that haven't happened yet at that year cannot have any effect on GDP. So I coded the above to get an NA for that year if the war hasn't happened yet:

| Country | Year | Years since War 1 | Years since War 2 | Long War 1 | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1970 | 50 | 25 | 0 | 3,000,000 |
| Iraq | 1970 | NA | 2 | NA | 4,000,000 |

I am trying to estimate regression:

lm(GDP ~ YearssinceWar1 + YearssinceWar2 + LongWar1 + LongWar2 + YearsSinceWar1*LongWar1, data = mydata)

Of course, R doesn't let me run this due to the NA variables. Is there any way around this to get the regression I want? The only other alternative I can see is setting the NA variables to 0, but this comes with its own set of problems (Like also coding LongWar1 as 0, which simply suggests a short war as this is a dummy varibale).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `Long War 1` variable? But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: the LongWar1 variable is a dummy variable which takes value 1 if the war lasted for more than 3 months and 0 otherwise. Ill edit it in the question as well. And thanks!

Comment: The basic statistical question here is answerable (and kjetilbhalvorsen's comment points to a useful thread) but this seems like a strange model to fit. There's other determinants of GDP, the causal direction between poverty/GDP and war is not as simple as this model assumes, among other things. At the very least you'd want to model a time series of GDP (or GDP per capita) per country, not use a single GDP value.

Comment: Thanks! My variable is not GDP and I do have a time series of the dependent variable, as well as other covariates. This was just a simpler example to make it easier for people to understand and help me with the statistical question. Thanks for the comment though!