# An issue in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, missing-data, odds-ratio

Hi I have a dataset including 885 observations. We are looking at the association between a set of predictors and the chance of pregnancy after embryo transfer. The response variable is dichotomous (pregnant or nonpregnant). Predictors are dichotomous (number of embryos; 1 or 2, time; before a certain date and after, embryo characteristics; A or B and two other parameters) and also size category with three levels (smaller, equal, and larger than x). A preliminary chi-square test on each of these variables shows a strong association between pregnancy and two of the predictors; recipients of two embryos and those with shape A had higher pregnancy compared to recipients of 1 embryo and those with shape B.

My question is: I am trying to run a GzLM to include all predictors and estimate the ORs. The issue that arises is that observations related to double embryo transfer (n=96) do not allow evaluation of embryo type or size at the same time, since it is two embryos that we are looking at (could be two A or 1 A and 1 B or other combinations). In other words, it makes sense to say embryo type or embryo size should be evaluated in those cases that received a single embryo. I would appreciate your advice on the right approach here. I preferably want to run all parameters in one analysis. Does it make sense if I run all predictors together and consider size and type as missing values in the case of double embryo recipients (98 missing values for 98 double embryos)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The following post might be of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258

Comment: Why have you made all your predictor variables categorical? Some are numerical (date and size, maybe others) and ideally those should be analyzed as such. Information is lost when you turn a number into a binary variable.