Logistic regression question about adjusting for a variable
I am trying to analyze a dataset using logistic regression with

1/0 (disease/no disease) outcome
sex (2 levels) and
age of diagnosis (grouped into 3 levels + NA).

The 0 outcome has no year of diagnosis, because they were never diagnosed, which I recoded into a new level. I was asked to adjust for age of diagnosis in the analysis, but if I try to put it into my regression, I get an error saying it can't run contrasts without 2 or more levels.
I could take a guess as to why it isn't working, but I don't know how else to adjust for year of diagnosis except to stratify, and I don't think that is what she was asking for. Google doesn't really know what I am asking about either.
How do I adjust for age of diagnosis in this situation? What am I missing?

Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258
