Categories automatically dropped in SPSS for my logistic regression
I have a problem with my logistic regression model. I use SPSS for analyzing the relationship between some categorical IV/2 numerical variables and customer churn (the well-known IBM Telco dataset). I selected the relevant dependent variable and all independent variables and marked some of them as categorical (last category as reference). I know that reference categories are not being shown, but why is it in my case? I don't know what to do as I need to analyze the effects.
 

Hi. It looks like that the coefficients of the reference categories are not been shown in the first image you shared, but this is to be expected, so how is it a problem? In fact, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "I know that reference categories are not being shown, but why is it in my case?", can you provide a specific example? Note that you can edit your question to add an example (it may be easier to read than discussing that in the comments).

This is a variant of a FAQ: see this site search or this one.

Thanks for the comments so far. Maybe it was not clear enough. Let‘s take a look at the variable MultipleLines, it is defined by 3 categories. Why can I only see one category with the coefficient? It must be two or not? For the variable Contract you can see 2 categories in the first image for interpretation.

I see. Looking at the dataset, the issue here is that you have nested variables. For example, the value of "MultipleLines" will always be "No phone service" if the value of "PhoneService" is no; "OnlineBackup" will always be "No internet service" if the value of InternetService is no, etc. I'd say this is normal not to have coefficients for those categories, as it is redundant information. This other thread addresses how to deal with nested variables in regression models in general: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model.

If you want more specific advice on how to model those nested variables in your situation, I'd suggest to edit your question to mention that you have nested variables, and importantly what is the goal of your model ultimately.

Note that the website aims at giving statistical advice (rather than software-specific advice), i.e. advice that could be useful to people who might face the same issue with other statistical software than SPSS. So if I were you, I wouldn't insist too much on the fact that you're using SPSS, and I'd rather focus on the statistical issues (i.e. what you are trying to do with your model, how you should interpret the coefficients, if you should exclude some variables from your model, how you should choose the reference categories, etc.).
